# Циклический сдвиг строки

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить. Нужно написать функцию, которая сдвигает строку на заданное количество символов.
Например, shift("abcd", 2) вернет "cdab"

```
function shift(line, move){
    var arr = line;
    var result = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(move > 0){
             result[i] = arr[i + move];
        }
        return result;
    }
}

document.write(shift('abcde',2));
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Циклически берем последний символ и вставляем его в начало текста

Comment: Сдвиг циклический? Разве не "cdab" при этом получится?

Comment: ну да cdab получается

Comment: Вам стоит привести свой код и указать, в чём возникло затруднение, чтобы вам могли помочь с этим заданием.

Comment: Также напомню, что вы всегда можете править свои посты: для этого достаточно воспользоваться ссылкой [edit] под текстом вашего поста. Важную информацию лучше включать непосредственно в исходное сообщение.

Comment: @D-side, мне показалось так и надо было. Тогда не совсем ясно как сдвигать надо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Идея такая, функцию сам сделаешь:

```js
var s = "123456";
document.body.innerHTML = s.slice(-2) + s.slice(0, -2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Кстати, ваш код почти выполнял требуемую задачу. Проблемы вашего решения:

- рано выходите из функции
- не учитываете границы массива
- сдвиг на "0" работал не как должен был
- не работали отрицательные сдвиги

Исправив эти ошибки можно было получить следующее решение:

```js
function shift(line, move){
    move = -move % line.length;
    if (move == 0) {
        return line;
    }

    move = (move < 0) ? line.length + move : move;
    var result = [],
        index;
    for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        index = (i + move) % line.length;
        result[i] = line[index];
    }
    return result.join('');
}

document.write('-5: ' + shift('abc', -5) + '<br />');
document.write('-4: ' + shift('abc', -4) + '<br />');
document.write('-3: ' + shift('abc', -3) + '<br />');
document.write('-2: ' + shift('abc', -2) + '<br />');
document.write('<br />');
document.write('-1: ' + shift('abc', -1) + '<br />');
document.write('+0: ' + shift('abc', 0) + '<br />');
document.write('+1: ' + shift('abc', 1) + '<br />');
document.write('<br />');
document.write('+2: ' + shift('abc', 2) + '<br />');
document.write('+3: ' + shift('abc', 3) + '<br />');
document.write('+4: ' + shift('abc', 4) + '<br />');
document.write('+5: ' + shift('abc', 5) + '<br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот циклический примерно так будет:

```
function shift(InputString, ShiftCount)
{

    var ReturnString = InputString;


    for(var i = 0; i < ShiftCount; i++)
    {
        ReturnString = ReturnString.substr(ReturnString.length-1) + ReturnString.substr(0, ReturnString.length-1);
    }


    return  ReturnString;
}

alert(shift("abcd", 2)); //cdab
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6wgbozpp/

Answer (score 0):

По примеру Qwertiy через прототип:

```
String.prototype.recursiveShift = function(n) { return this.slice(-n) + this.slice(0,-n) }

console.log("hello world".recursiveShift(5))
console.log("world hello ".recursiveShift(7))
console.log("123456789".recursiveShift(3))
```